# Excel can't cut, copy, paste or paint format

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm using Microsoft Excel 2007. Recently it has developed a very annoying problem: From time to time, I am unable to use cut, copy, paste or paint format.

The only remedy seems to be a complete computer reboot. Closing Excel and re-opening does not solve the problem.

What can I do?

Comment: See also http://superuser.com/questions/405168/missing-paste-special-options-in-excel-2010

Answer (score 1):

I just had my son figure it out for me. The culprit is Skype's *Click to Call* feature. Removing it fixes the problem.