# I only have the "Keep Text Only" option when pasting in Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

A couple of days ago I changed my Outlook 2010 default settings for pasting, so they all used "keep text only". I now regret that decision and have changed the settings back to the defaults.

However, on pasting I only have the option to paste as Text. The other options are not available.

So far I have

- Removed Skype click to call
- Repair install of Office
- File - Options - Mail - Editor Options - Advanced - Cut, Copy and Paste   changed all settings to defaults
- In the same page, checked "Show paste options button when content is pasted"
- Disabled Evernote add-in (just in case)
- Rebooted

This is the same problem as [here](https://superuser.com/questions/405168/missing-paste-special-options-in-excel-2010), but in Outlook instead of Excel

Answer (score 0):

Try renaming the following registry:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Word\Data
```

Restart Outlook/Word, and the key will be recreated with the default settings.

Comment: Didn't have change to try this out, as scanpst worked for me. Thanks anyway